# How to make a arrow dialog box in Material UI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I know how to make an arrow box (div) using custom CSS and HTML, but I don't know how to implement the same in Material UI and react js, Below is the code to do the same with custom CSS.
How to use the same CSS in material UI is my question.
Codepen example [div which contains an arrow](https://codepen.io/lideo/pen/jawFy)

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-right-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a dropdown box? The point of material-ui is that they have custom input components already, no need to add your own css.

Comment: No i didn't mean dropdown box i meant a dialog box which contains and arrow directing towards some content like this [codepen link](https://codepen.io/lideo/pen/jawFy)

Answer (score 0):

Like @paddotk said material ui have their own components you just need to look through the docs.

What you are looking for can be found here - https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#arrow-tooltips

You can use the `arrow` prop to give your tooltip an arrow indicating which element it refers to.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

export default function ArrowTooltips() {
  return (
    <Tooltip title="Add" arrow>
      <Button>Arrow</Button>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

Comment: But i want to customize the dialog component , using tooltip won't help in this case i guess

Comment: why cant you customise the tooltip?

Comment: I'm trying to build a user tutorial kind of thing, i.e., when the user logs in and lands on the page , I want to show the tutorial by a dialog component showing user where to click and what to do.So basically the dialog component pointing towards a button telling user what to do.So i thought of having a arrow dialog box pointing towards a button